# How to send coverage result from TravisCI to Coveralls?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, travis-ci, jestjs, coveralls

Now building a react app made by `create-react-app`.

In my `package.json`, I installed some dependencies. The full list is here:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jest-cli": "^22.4.3",
    "raven-js": "^3.25.1",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-raven": "^1.2.3",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "0.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-jest": "^22.4.3",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.1",
    "coveralls": "^3.0.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "jest": "^22.4.3",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.3.2"
  }
}
```

Also created a `.travis.yml` file. Want to test the codes on TravisCI:

.travis.yml

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "8"

before_script:
  - npm install
  - npm install coveralls

script:
  - jest --coverage --coverageReporters=text-lcov | coveralls
```

But when the TravisCI run the task, it's console log shows:

```
...
$ jest --coverage --coverageReporters=text-lcov | coveralls
PASS src/sum.test.js
  ✓ adds 1 + 2 to equal 3 (7ms)
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.629s
Ran all test suites.
/home/travis/build/[MY_GITHUB]/[MY_PROJECT]/node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js:18
        throw err;
        ^
Bad response: 500 {"message":"Build processing error.","error":true,"url":""}
The command "jest --coverage --coverageReporters=text-lcov | coveralls" exited with 1.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

Why can't send coverage result to coveralls?

Comment: Did you register at Coveralls.io?

Comment: @iBug Yes. I register at Coveralls.io.

Answer (score 1):

I have put together a simple repository to demonstrate using `jest` with `travis` and `coveralls` here:

https://github.com/AaronWatters/hello_jest

It uses `jest.config.js` to tell jest to put the coverage report at
`"./tests/coverage"` and then the `coveralls` directive in `package.json`
is

```
"coveralls": "jest --coverage && cat ./tests/coverage/lcov.info | coveralls",
```

I'm sorry it is so convoluted but it seems to work even though it's not
as simple as what you were trying to do.  It also does not use `react` but
I don't think it should be an issue to use the same approach with a `react` component.

Please see the repository for all the gory details.

Also please post an issue at the repository if you find problems with the approach or if you have other suggestions or comments.